# How to get the active price of the selected variable product

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to access the product price of the selected product so I can use it in my PHP code to do some calculations. I have found a code that is working only partially. The code only displays the price of the first variable product. When I change the value from 0 to 1 in his code line it will display the price of the second variant. $availablevariations[0]['variation_id'].
I am trying to get the current price of the product based on whatever option is selected from the drop down list. 
Here is the code that I am using which is not working the way I would would like it to

```
    // Get current product variation price
    global $product;

    //get the sale price of the product whether it be simple, grouped or variable
    echo $saleprice = getpostmeta( gettheID(), '_price', true);

    //get the regular price of the product, but of a simple product
    $regular_price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);

    //oh, the product is variable to $sale_price is empty? Lets get a variation price

    if ($regular_price == ""){
    #Step 1: Get product varations
    $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

    #Step 2: Get product variation id
    $variation_id=$available_variations[0]['variation_id']; // Getting the variable id of just the 1st product. You can loop $available_variations to get info about each variation.

    #Step 3: Create the variable product object
    $variable_product1= new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );

    #Step 4: You have the data. Have fun :)
    $regular_price = $variable_product1 ->regular_price;
```

}

```
        echo "<br> $regular_price ---This is the price I am trying to fix "
```

I need this code to make some operation with the current variable product price, so if you want to see, the link is http://www.emotionadv.it/shop/volantini/volantino/ , when i change an attribute the price changes.
I want to get that price to use in table under.

Answer (score 2):

WooCommerce has a custom trigger that fires when a variation is found. The following will run when a variation is found... and dump the `variation` variable in the console so you can see what is available to you.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {

    $( '.variations_form' ).each( function() {

        // when variation is found, do something
        $(this).on( 'found_variation', function( event, variation ) {
            console.log(variation);
        });

    });

} );
```

It `variation` should look something like this:

There are 2 variations that should be useful for you.

```
variation.price_html = "<span class="price"><span class="amount">$40.00</span></span>";
```

You might be able to pull the price out of this string. If not, then you can use ajax to return the numerical price from a product object using `variation.variation_id`.

```
$product = wc_get_product($variation_id);
$price = $product->get_price();
```

Comment: The first piece of code i have to put into function.php or single product/add_to_cart/variable.php

Comment: If you mean the `jQuery` bit, you need to make that a separate script and load it. See [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

Comment: Code is really hard to read in the comments, but I don't think the unavailable text string (which will read something like "This variation is not available") will be pertinent to your original question. Have you tried my code at all?

Answer (score 1):

i have make a separate script with your jQuery code, and i load it  the file's name is "prova", but now i don't know how to catch the variable price, i try with $product = wc_get_product($variation_id); $price = $product->get_price(); i put this piece of code after wp_enqueue_script('prova'); but $price is the min price of the variable product.